# ShowStandardCancelButton takes me to homepage insted of previous page

Tags: asp.net, button, cancel-button

As the topic mentions, I want to create a cancel button that takes me to the previous page. I am using the standard cancel button. I want a cancel button which only takes me one step back, to my previous page.

```
<wssuc:ButtonSection runat="server" ShowStandardCancelButton="true">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with javascript easily and without server control. No postbacks ;)

```
 window.history.back();
```

But if you insist on a server control...

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClik="javascript:window.history.back();" Text="Cancel" Visible="True" />
```

Comment: Found the answer. Similar to yours. Thanks anyways: 
<asp:Button id="CancelBtn" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" Text="Cancel" runat="server" OnClientClick="history.back(); return false" />